# slf4j logger Info level not logging in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, slf4j

I have class with functions and I use slf4j logger in them. When testing those functions without server, logger works as configured in log4j.xml file. The level of logging is "info" by default. So, with the following code I get this output:

```
    logger.error("get tree of id = " + id);
    logger.warn("get tree of id = " + id);
    logger.info("get tree of id = " + id);
    logger.debug("get tree of id = " + id);
    logger.trace("get tree of id = " + id);
```

Output:

```
    ERROR: com.app.models.DatabaseModel - get tree of id = 1470
    WARN : com.app.models.DatabaseModel - get tree of id = 1470
    INFO : com.app.models.DatabaseModel - get tree of id = 1470
```

But when I run Tomcat Server, the output is different from the same code:

```
    ERROR: com.app.models.DatabaseModel - get tree of id = 1470
    WARN : com.app.models.DatabaseModel - get tree of id = 1470
```

What is the problem here? How to configure slf4j to work on server the same way as given in configuration file?

Comment: What is the location of your log4j.xml file?

Comment: oh, I see what you say, I noticed now that there I have 2 log4j.xml files and configured only one of them. Works now. Still don't understand why there are 2 of them by default.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [mad_fox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3225260/mad-fox) I figured out that I had multiple log4j.xml files in my directories and I was configuring the wrong one. Solved